# Session object is null in page_load on 64 bit

Tags: asp.net, 2007

I am having a strange problem. I am porting an asp.net web application to sharepoint (as a web part) and I've converted most of it to a webpart that loads an .ascx user control. However I have some pop-up windows that I've left as .aspx pages.

This works fine under MOSS 2007 on Windows 2003 server, however, when I install the same package on Win 2008 64 bit, MOSS 2007, the web part works fine, however the popup .aspx page does not.

In Page_Load I am looking for something stored in the Session object and here it is mysteriously null. In the webpart it is ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Whats the URL to the pages / where are they stored?

Answer (score 1):

Anders has a good point. Are your pages running in the SP context i.e. in the _layouts folder? Or are they hosted by a dedicated IIS site? If the latter is true, then that's the problem.

Comment: they are running in the _layouts folder of SP (installed with WSP together with the web part.
I've ended up reworking the solution so that it doesn't use session at all, it was the easiest.